# Graphical issues installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, livecd, troubleshooting, graphic-card

I'm trying to install Mint on a desktop and I'm having some issues getting it to cooperate. When I run from the Live DVD and allow it to start automatically, I get this on the screen:

[image: Normal startup]

If I select the safe startup, it seems to load the CLI normally. However, at a certain point my monitor displays "OUT OF BOUNDS." Attempting to change resolution/refresh rate with [Ctrl Alt +/-] results in the message "DVI NO SIGNAL" blinking in with a black screen.

I *assume* this is a graphics card **issue**-- the computer in question has no inbuilt VGA onboard, so I'm using a spare. Is there any way I can fix this without scrapping the card?

**Edits in bold.**

**Update 1. I'll try to keep this updated for future needs-- I know I can't stand when a problem on an internet forum is solved without future input.**

**I am still trying to get to the command prompt -- closest I got was by Escaping out of the safe mode install, which gave me four colored dots, and eventually "Linux Mint 17.1" over them, however, this just kicked me back to the monitor OUT OF RANGE error.**

Comment: During the BIOS initialisation your computer normally tells you what kind of graphics card **is** installed. Including that information, and e.g. the make and model of your PC, in your question might help getting more specific solutions for this problem. Since you can select safe startup, can we assume that grub displays normally? Or are you selecting that blind.

Comment: @Anthon: This is through the LiveCD menu of Mint 17.1 -- Grub isn't installed yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue I had a lot with Linux Mint and Ubuntu, you should get the appropriate graphics driver, for amd it's fglrx (not updates) and for nvidia it's nvidia-current.

Use apt-get install and the command line for installation.

But before you do anything collect your graphic card's type and search for it.
There may be another solution then.